# How to insert the value to forignkey column using C# mvc entityframwork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an employee Salary table, The primary key is SSID.So I have created another table Employee information SSID will be a foreign key on that table. Now the problem is I want to insert the value to Employee information table.

the issue is how to insert value the Forignkey column using MVC or how we bring the primary key value to the foreign key.

I am new to this. I am doing CRUD operation .is i need to join the table. because I am using entity framework and angular js so how we write the code MVC controller and view.please

Comment: have you rechecked entity framework documentation ? I'm sure the information you need setting somewhere there.

Comment: I checked but i could not find th information

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

Comment: I already check not working for me...you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

You have to build an association between the two tables.

```
[Table("EmployeeSalary")]
public class EmployeeSalary
{
    public EmployeeSalary()
    {
       EmployeeInfo = new HashSet<EmployeeInfo>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Int16 SSID { get; set; }
    ….
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeInfo> EmployeeInfo { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public Int16 SSID { get; set; }
    ….
    [ForeignKey("SSID")]
    public virtual EmployeeSalary EmployeeSalary { get; set; }    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, employee information could have many employee salaries hence your models should look like;

```
public class EmployeeInformation{
  public int EmployeeInformationId {get;set;}
  public virtual List<EmployeeSalary> EmployeeSalaries {get;set;}
}

public class EmployeeSalary{
  public int EmployeeSalaryId {get;set;}
  public int EmployeeInformationId {get;set;}

  [ForeignKey("EmployeeInformationId")]
  public virtual EmployeeInformation EmployeeInformation {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your Employee Information view, you should have a link or a button that redirect you to add Employee Salaries. This link should contain the Employee Information Id inside an anonymous object.

```
@Html.Action("AddSalary", new { id = Model.EmployeeeInformationId })
```

In my example above, I used the action name "AddSalary" there should be a AddSalary method in the Controller to handle this request. So in your EmployeeInformation Controller you should have;

```
public class EmployeeInformationController:Controller
{
  ...

  public ActionResult AddSalary(int eId)
  {
    new EmployeeSalary es = new EmployeeSalary();
    es.EmployeeInformationId = eId;
    return View(es);
  }
}
```

Your AddSalary view should use the EmployeeSalary Model, then with the controller action example above, it will auto populate the Employee Information Id with the one passed through the url.